# Used html2canvas to capture image, tried to upload it to server, but it wasn't working all the time

Tags: php, html2canvas

I got a module for e-signing purpose, allow user to open a document, sign on it, and upload it to my server. So I used HTML2Canvas to capture the signed document, and then upload the image to my server. My issue here is the module is not stable, sometimes it's working but sometimes the uploaded image was 0 bytes (empty). Would like to know do anybody able to advise on this. Below are my scripts:

HTML2Canvas

```
<div id="pdf" style="page-break-after: always; padding:3px;">
  Some codes
</div>
```

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#submit3").click(function(e) {

                html2canvas(document.querySelector('#pdf'), {scale: 2}).then(canvas => {

                    var sono = "<?php echo $sono; ?>";
                    var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                      xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
                      xhr.send(photo + "sono=" + sono);

                });

            })
        })
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

    /*Get data */
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $fsono = strpos($data, 'sono=');
    $sono = substr($data, $fsono + 5, 4);

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $fname = 'Signed-'.$sono.'.jpg'; // name the file
    //$fname = '123';

    $file = fopen("uploads/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
    fwrite($file, $data); //save data
    fclose($file);
?>
```